# Returning back to the previous application?

Tags: android

I have following two applications, A & B.

`Application A` has a `service` which waits for application B to come in foregrouond. Now, when application B comes in foreground, service of A calls an activity of A which perform certain task.

Now from this activity of A, I want to go back to application B, from where I came to activity of B.

What I am trying right now is:

In service,

```
  String foregroundProcess = getForgroundProcessName();
```

Now if it matches to a desired process, I am calling an activity:

```
Intent intent = new     Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityOfApplicatinA.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                                intent.putExtra("foregroundProcess",foregroundProcess);

startActivity(intent);
```

Now, from this activity `ActivityOfApplicatinA`, I want to return back to application `B`, which is done by:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        name = intent.getStringExtra("foregroundProcess");

        Log.d(TAG, "The foreground process was:" + name);
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(name);
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
        finish();
```

The issue with my approach is that I am not returning to the previous state of application B. It simply relaunch the application B. I don't want this to happen. I want to open application B, with previous state.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: why don't you just simply use finish() instead of starting activity b again? Like, do your job in A and finish it.

Comment: Calling finish() doesn't return to application B. It returns to MainActivity of application A. A has two activities, one is called by service (to perform certain task), and another one, which is mainactivity, which start the service.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = m_context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageNameOfAppB);
LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

**NOTE:**
*Works only if the application B was launched before and in activity history stac*k.

Comment: Are you sure? How would I know the activity name of application B? I know only package name of applicationB.

Comment: `Works only if the application B was launched before and in activity history stack.` Why to ensure this?

Comment: It doesn't work. Nothing changes. It is giving me the same result, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You want to bring your activity B to front which is launched already right? That's what docs say: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Added in API level 3
int FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.

Comment: When I try, it's just working fine, moving back to Application B's current situation, doesn't launch it from the start and keep the information in it. Are you talking about the animations or can you clarify the problem? Because Application B's state doesn't change at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113301/discussion-between-burak-day-and-learner).